# Recuperar id en un onclick Recycler

Tags: java, android

Mi problem es saber como adaptar este tutorial 
https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/introduction-to-the-new-lollipop-activity-transitions--cms-23711

ya que tengo un Recycler utilizando un adapter modificado (creo que se dice así, soy nuevo) y quiero obtener un id por ejemplo del titulo(nombre) de cada ítem, ya que son diferentes, y que cree el activity detalle con la información adecuada. Como verán en el row del Recycler no aparece el txtD pero si en el activity detalle xml, y esa en la información que quiero pasar ademas del imageview que es compartido.

```
public class T_Fisica implements Materias {
private final int image_t;
private final String nombre_t, text_t, text_d;


public class T_Fisica implements Materias {

private final int image_t;
private final String nombre_t, text_t, text_d;


public T_Fisica(int image_t, String nombre_t, String text_t, String text_d) {
    this.image_t = image_t;
    this.nombre_t = nombre_t;
    this.text_t = text_t;
    this.text_d= text_d;
}

   public int getimage_t() {return image_t;}

   public String getNombre_t() {return nombre_t;}

   public String getText_t() {return text_t;}

   public String getText_d(){return text_d;}

   public int getId() {
   return nombre_t.hashCode();
   }

@Override
public int getViewType() {
    return 1;
    }
}
```

Interface Materias

```
public interface Materias {
int getViewType();
}
```

Item xml (row)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:shadowColor="#212121"
        android:shadowDx="-8"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textColor="#fafafa"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="440dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#455a64"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card2"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#c9cd5c"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView91"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView3"
        android:textColor="#eceff1"
        android:textSize="12.5sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:transitionGroup="false" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card3"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:transitionName="@string/image_transition" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/comillas"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>
```

activity detalle xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card19"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:transitionName="@string/image_transition" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="384dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="72dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/card20"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtD"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity detalle

```
public class Activity_Detalle extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String ID = "ID";
    //public items
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__detalle);
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    //nombres=T_Fisica.getItem(getIntent().getIntExtra(ID,0));
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element));

    String det="";
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra!=null){
        det=extra.getString("DETALLE");
    }
    TextView txtD = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtD);
    txtD.setText(det);
    }

}
```

Recycler

```
public  class T_FAdaptador extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private final int ITEM1 = 1;
private final int ITEM2 = 2;

private List<Materias> items = new ArrayList<>();

private static Context context;

static class Item1Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public final TextView nombre, text;
    public final ImageView imagen;
    public Item1Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView90);
        imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(imageView2);
        text=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView91);
       // det=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtD);

        itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity_Detalle.class);
                intent.putExtra("DETALLE", det.getText());
                ActivityOptionsCompat option = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, imagen, context.getString(R.string.image_transition));
                context.startActivity(intent, option.toBundle());
                ((Activity) context).getWindow().setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_exit));
                }

        });
    }

    static class Item2Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public final TextView nombre, text;
        public final ImageView imagen;
        public Item2Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nombre= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView90);
            imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(imageView2);
            text=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView91);
        }
    }}

public T_FAdaptador(Context context, List<Materias> items) {
    this.context=context;
    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    switch (viewType){
        case ITEM1: viewHolder = new Item1Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_fisica,parent,false));
            break;
        case ITEM2: viewHolder = new Item1Holder.Item2Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_prueba,parent,false));
            break;
        default: viewHolder = new Item1Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_fisica,parent));
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)){
        case ITEM1:
            T_Fisica item1 = (T_Fisica) items.get(position);
            Item1Holder item1Holder = (Item1Holder)holder;
            item1Holder.nombre.setText(item1.getNombre_t());
            item1Holder.text.setText(item1.getText_t());
            item1Holder.imagen.setImageResource(item1.getimage_t());
            //item1Holder.det.setText(item1.getText_d());
            break;
        case ITEM2:
            T_Algebra item2 = (T_Algebra) items.get(position);
            Item1Holder.Item2Holder item2Holder = 
(Item1Holder.Item2Holder)holder;
            item2Holder.nombre.setText(item2.getNombre_t());
            item2Holder.text.setText(item2.getText_t());
            item2Holder.imagen.setImageResource(item2.getimage_t());
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getViewType();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
}
```

y por ultimo el activity donde se aloja el Recycler

```
public class Fisica extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView reciclador;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lmanager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adaptador;
private List<Materias> items = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fisica);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Movimientos");
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.enter_activity));
    //getWindow().setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_exit));


    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.mruymruvmenor, "MRU y MRUV", "El movimiento rectilíneo uniforme (m.r.u.) es aquel en el que la trayectoria es una línea recta y la velocidad es constante.El MRUV es aquel movimiento en que la velocidad varía uniformemente con el tiempo y, por lo tanto, la aceleración permanece constante.",getString(R.string.MruyMruv)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.clibreytverticalmenor, "Caida Libre y Tiro Vertical", "Se trata de un movimiento rectilíneo uniforme variado, también conocido como MRUV. En un tiro vertical, la velocidad cambia y existe una aceleración que está dada por la acción de la gravedad. El tiro vertical, cuya dirección puede ser descendente o ascendente, tiene una velocidad inicial que resulta diferente a cero.",getString(R.string.TVerticalyCLibre)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.tirooblicuomenor, "Tiro Oblicuo", "Resultado de imagen para definicion tiro oblicuo\n" +
            "Tiro oblicuo. Se trata de una particularidad del \"Tiro parabólico\", por lo tanto es un “movimiento rectilíneo uniforme” en su desarrollo horizontal y un “movimiento uniformemente variado” en su desarrollo vertical. Pero, en el eje vertical se comporta como el movimiento de “Caída Libre”.",getString(R.string.TOblicuo)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.mcuymcuamenor, "MCU y MCUA", "MCU y MCUA son movimiento de un cuerpo por una trayectoria circular, tanto si te trata de un movimiento uniforme o uniformemente acelerado. Lo único que cambian son las formas de expresar el espacio, la velocidad y la aceleración.",getString(R.string.McuyMcuv)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.dinamicamenor, "Dinamica y Dinamica Del Circular", "La dinámica es la parte de la física que estudia la relación existente entre las fuerzas que actúan sobre un cuerpo y los efectos que se producirán sobre el movimiento de ese cuerpo.",getString(R.string.Dinamica)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.mgravitatoriomenor, "Movimiento Gravitatorio", "Estudia las fuerzas que infuyen en el movimientos de los planetas.",getString(R.string.MGravitatorio)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.fuerzaelasticamenor, "Fuerza Elastica", "La fuerza elástica es la ejercida por objetos tales como resortes, que tienen una posición normal, fuera de la cual almacenan energía potencial y ejercen fuerzas.",getString(R.string.FElastica)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.moamenor, "Movimiento Oscilatorio Armonico", "Se trata de un movimiento armónico simple. El movimiento oscilatorio es un movimiento en torno a un punto de equilibrio estable. Este puede ser simple o completo. Los puntos de equilibrio mecánico son, en general, aquellos en los cuales la fuerza neta que actúa sobre la partícula es cero.",getString(R.string.Mos)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.estaticamenor, "Estatica", "La estática es la rama de la mecánica clásica que analiza las cargas (fuerza, par / momento) y estudia el equilibrio de fuerzas en los sistemas físicos en equilibrio estático, es decir, en un estado en el que las posiciones relativas de los subsistemas no varían con el tiempo.",getString(R.string.Estatica)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.pendulosimplemenor, "Pendulo Simple", "Un péndulo simple se define como una partícula de masa m suspendida del punto O por un hilo inextensible de longitud l y de masa despreciable. Si la partícula se desplaza a una posición q0 (ángulo que hace el hilo con la vertical) y luego se suelta, el péndulo comienza a oscilar.",getString(R.string.PenduloSimple)));
    items.add(new T_Fisica(R.drawable.hidrostaticamenor, "Hidrostatica", "Se describe como presión al acto y resultado de comprimir, estrujar o apretar; a la coacción que se puede ejercer sobre un sujeto o conjunto; o la magnitud física que permite expresar el poder o fuerza que se ejerce sobre un elemento o cuerpo en una cierta unidad de superficie.",getString(R.string.Hidrostatica)));


    reciclador = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
    reciclador.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    reciclador.setLayoutManager(lmanager);
    adaptador = new T_FAdaptador(this, items);
    reciclador.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

}
```

disculpen la desprolijidad si falta o sobra información díganme que edito la pregunta, agradecería mucho si me ayudan a lograrlo.

Comment: busca un poco por SOES creo que es preguntada muy frecuentamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener el índice del elemento que el usuario ha tocado puedes usar dentro del listener en el adaptador:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            T_Fisica item = (T_Fisica) items.get(getAdapterPosition());
            String nombre = item.getNombre_t();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity_Detalle.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre", nombre);

            // Resto del código...
        }

    });
```

Y recuperas el extra desde `Activity_Detalle`

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String nombre = extra.getString("nombre");
```

Comment: lo que quiero es obtener el id o algo que le diga al activity detalle cual item se selecciono y así rellenarlo con la información que no se muestra en el item.                                                                          
Error:(44, 37) error: non-static variable items cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(44, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable getNombre_t
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: No había notado que el ViewHolder era estático, yo personalmente no lo uso de esa manera. `getAdapterposition()` te dará el índice del elemento que el usuario ha presionado, así que podrías usarlo para obtener los datos de ese elemento. Así que si quieres que sea estático puedes pasarlo como parámetro desde `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: como lo usas?? soy nuevo asi que todo lo estoy aprendiendo. No se si ayuda pero los items no cambian de orden, digo por si es mas sencillo obtener el ID.

Comment: Me refiero a la palabra `static` en la clase `Item1Holder`, puede ser que no necesite ser estática, de esta forma podrías acceder a los elementos de la lista de items. Por otro lado reitero, que para obtener el elemento utilices `getAdapterPosition()`, esta función devuelve el índice del elemento selecccionado por el usuario.

Comment: Dale en breve lo pruebo y te aviso cómo va. Muchas gracias por la paciencia

Comment: bien si hago eso  en getNombre_t me sale cannot resolve method. Ahora es posible que un String por ejemplo en mi arraylist items.add...R.string.MruyMruv ese valor es la descripcion y solo quiero que se muestre en el activity detalle no en el item del recycler

Comment: @Carlos He modificado la respuesta... es necesario hacer un cast al item para poder acceder al método `getNombre_t()` ya que se considera del tipo `Materias` y no del tipo `T_Fisica`. Por otro lado, pasandole el valor de `nombre` directamente a `Activity_Detalle` por medio del `Intent`, no es necesario desplegarlo en el CardView.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por todo, estoy leyendo todo lo que puedo para resolverlo. Ahora el problema seria que cuando se abre el segundo activity esta todo en blanco ni siquiera se comparte la imagen. ¿Tiene algo que ver que en el primer activity no exista un view para la descripcion y en el segundo si?

Comment: Hola, en este caso puedes pasar el identificador del `drawable` a `Activity_Detalle.java`, y si no se despliega probablemente se deba a que al `activity__detalle.xml` le falta una etiqueta `Layout` padre que contenga todas las cardviews y demás.
Esto se saldría un poco del alcance de esta pregunta así que te recomiendo que realices una nueva, específicamente para preparar y desplegar la información adecuadamente en un layout.

Comment: Bien formularé otra pregunta. Ahora lo que no me queda claro es porque no se pasa la información del textview. Podrías fijarte los xml con detenimiento, verás que hay información que solo se muestra en el activity detalle. Pero que está en el Array que rellena el recycler. Son los últimos string. Lo último que se me ocurre hacer sería compartir un textview que cuando aparece en el activity detalle cambié su contenido por el string

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu paciencia lo logre por fin. Despues de tener en cuenta toda tu ayuda salio cambiando en vez el getNombre._t por Text_d que contenia la descripcion. y en el segundo activity solo agregue :                                                                                     
TextView nombres= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtD);  y     nombres.setText(nombre);